# Break the line when reached to end of TextInput view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to break the line of text in TextInput when reaches to end of TextInput.
[image]

I don't want to increase the height of TextInput. It will be scrollable inside TextInput.

I did try `FlexWrap` but it didn't work for me.

Thanks!!!

Comment: di you try regex?

Comment: for scrollable use scroll-x

Comment: I just want to be clear, is using `TextArea` out of the question? You can make it look like a `TextInput` with 1 row only.

Comment: how regex will help, regex help me validating I think. Let's say if I enter 10 alphabets the it should break the line automatically every time after having 10 alphabets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `multiline={true}`:

```
<TextInput
    multiline={true}
    numberOfLines={4}
    style={{ height:200, textAlignVertical: 'top',}}
    ...
/>
```

Comment: mutliLine will let me have multiple line when I press enter but what I want is when I reach to end of box while typing it should break the line automatically.

Comment: @ShanAlam here is the working demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-fire-ou63i?file=/src/App.js